# Apache view access history of specific file

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-12.04

I was on a support chat with someone for a piece of software I have installed on my Ubuntu server, and he had direct access to an SQL file that has valuable information on it, because he knew my domain name, and I was instructed to name the SQL file something specific as per their documentation. So I realized he could download the file if he wanted to. I'm trying to figure out if I can check some access log somewhere on my server to see if an IP address other than my own accessed/downloaded this file from my server. Is this possible without already having had a monitoring software installed?

I checked most obvious places already of course in /var/log/apache2, but I knew that wasn't the right place because `cat access.log | grep -i ".sql"` didn't even show that I accessed the file, when I have.

Comment: Keep in mind log rotation may have moved away your old accesses of the file.

Comment: Are you certain they got something by using apache? If this is their custom software, maybe it exposed the files?
If you are certain, and your log files haven't been rotated, make sure to double check your log configuration in your httpd.conf, or whever it might be at. Maybe run grep -i log /etc/apache2/*.conf to double check?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out my own question. The information I was looking for was in `/var/log/apache2/access.log`. What I did was I searched for another file I knew he had accessed, and this is how I found his IP address, so I simply did `cat access.log | grep -i "his IP here"` and it revealed all of the files he accessed, none of which where the SQL file, so all is well.